# Passing Parameters from one XAML page to another

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Tile Layout Control with of course Tiles in it which I use to let  user navigate through pages, I simply want to pass some parameters like strings or integers between my pages... How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this approach or just by passing data between classes

http://msmvps.com/blogs/siva/archive/2007/05/11/storing-application-wide-data-the-wpf-way.aspx

```
 Application.Current.Properties["youvalueindex"];
```

Comment: Sorry me being newbie, but where to put this, in destination page? or the page which the tiles are in?

Comment: is there any sample I can use?

Comment: @Pooria Khodaveissi please refer to the link for example

Answer (score 1):

Generally you will have some sort of manager controlling your windows.  That manager would handle passing the data between the windows.  The windows generally should not know anything about each other.

**Simplistic Example**

```
class Manager
{
   ...
   void DoSomething()
   {
      ViewModelA vma = new ViewModelA();
      WindowA wa = new WindowA();
      wa.DataContext = vma;
      wa.ShowDialog();
      ViewModelB vmb = new ViewModelB();
      vmb.SharedData = vma.SharedData;
      WindowB wb = new WindowB();
      wb.DataContext = vmb;
      wb.ShowDialog();
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the time you've put on this but already got my answer,
thanks again Malgaur

Comment: No problem, that is the nature of this forum ;-)  Do be careful not to abuse the accepted answer, though.  In essence, it is a global variable.  You should only use that approach in extreme cases.  If you require its use regularly, you probably have a poor overall design and should consider refactoring.  Good luck.